# KDE -- undo "no title bar and frame"

Tags: kde

I set a certain window to "no title bar and frame". Now I want to undo that setting. Normally, I would right-click on the top bar, and choose the windows settings I want, but the top bar is now hidden.

Comment: alt+f3 should bring out the top bar menu.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked and answered already, albeit on a different site:
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=109268

Just go to: System Settings/Window Management/Windows Rules

You will see a list of all windows that have special rules. Select the desired rule, and click on "Modify".

Another, probably easier solution is to use the keyboard shortcut alt+f3, which should bring out the top bar menu. This solution is from bac0n's comment on the question.

Comment: You could add the contents of bac0n's comment to your answer as well.